# Textbox masking - How to put a comma and .00 in a textbox

Tags: javascript, css

i did research about textbox masking but its all complicated. Is there an easy way to put a comma and .00 in a textbox?

Here's my code

```
<tbody id="tbody_addIa_ow">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
   <input required type="text" disabled name="owner_kind_ia[]"  class="form-control char_only limit" />
    </td>
    <td>
  <input required type="text" disabled name="owner_area_ia[]"  class="form-control num_only limit" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <input required type="text" disabled id="txtNum" name="owner_value_ia[]"  class="form-control num_only ia_val limit" />
  </td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

i want to put a comma and .00 in owner_value_ia[] while typing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if by "Is there an easy way to put a comma and .00 in a textbox?" you mean: "is there a native way of doing this?" then no.

Comment: Got it. i put 
$('.ia_val').mask("#,##0.00", {reverse: true}); in javascript and jquery.mask.min.js

Comment: The question seems to be about js/jquery more so than PHP/codeigniter.

Comment: Are you okay with using plugin ?

Comment: uhm, yea? now my problem is, its not totaling the 2 value because it has comma.

Comment: i think you can use span at the and of input , and by using after psedo element give content ', .00' or whaterver you want and play with span after's position
Ref  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but this content of yours will be static and if want dynamic, you can change content value using attr(), see that for reference......

```css
input[name='owner_area_ia[]'] + span:after {
  height : 50px;
  width : 50px;
  content : ', .00';
  position : relative;
  left : -50px;
  color : darkgray;
}
```

```html
<tbody id="tbody_addIa_ow">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
   <input required type="text" disabled name="owner_kind_ia[]"  class="form-control char_only limit" />
    </td>
    <td>
  <input required type="text" disabled name="owner_area_ia[]"  class="form-control num_only limit" />
      <span></span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input required type="text" disabled id="txtNum" name="owner_value_ia[]"  class="form-control num_only ia_val limit" />
  </td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```